# Ratio of area of triangle to that formed by its medians

Tags: geometry, contest-math

What is the ratio of the area of a triangle $ABC$ to the area of the triangle whose sides are equal in length to the medians of triangle $ABC$?

I see an obvious method of brute-force wherein I can impose a coordinate system onto the figure. But is there a better solution?

Comment: There is, it can be proved using a variety of ways that its 4/3. Let me search some links for you.

Comment: Ok, so I seem to have lost the better links, so here is one of what turned up in Google:     jwilson.coe.uga.edu/emt725/Medians.Triangle/Area.Medians.Tri.html

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Let $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ be the side midpoints. Construct the parallelogram PYBZ and connect PC.

By construction, PY = BZ = AZ, PY || AZ and then PYZA is also a parallelogram, which leads to AP || ZY || XC and AP = XC, and in turn the parallelogram APCX. Thus, PC = AX and the sides of the triangle PCZ are the medians of ABC.

The parallelogram PYZA also yields AQ = QY = $\frac14$AC and then

$$\frac{Area_{PCZ}}{Area_{ABC}}=\frac{Area_{QCZ}}{Area_{AZC}}=\frac{QC}{AC} = \frac34
$$

Answer (score 0):

The area of a triangle given its medians is $(4/3)\sqrt{m(m-m_a)(m-m_b)(m-m_b)}$
and the area of a triangle formed by the medians of the first triangle is,by heron's formula, $\sqrt{m(m-m_a)(m-m_b)(m-m_b)}$. Dividing the two we get

$$(4/3)\sqrt{m(m-m_a)(m-m_b)(m-m_b)}/\sqrt{m(m-m_a)(m-m_b)(m-m_b)}=4/3$$

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).